# Enviar mensagem para TV conectada na rede

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Como faço para enviar uma mensagem para uma TV conectada na rede usando **Delphi7**.

Ex.: Tenho um sistema que controla filas de atendimento ao público, preciso mostrar a próxima senha chamada em uma TV que está conectada na rede.

Comment: obs: você ainda não tem um sistema que controla filas de atendimento ao público, você ainda está construindo ele. Qual a sua dúvida? O que você já tem pronto?

Comment: Estou construindo o sistema, a dúvida é como enviar a mensagem com a próxima senha para uma tv ligada na rede

Comment: Ligar o computador a uma TV com a saída HDMI não resolve?

Comment: Mas nesse caso como faço para enviar a mensagem? preciso trabalhar em rede

Comment: Depende de quais conexões tem a sua TV. Tem como ligar ela em rede?

Comment: Não vale a pena fazer um aplicativo pra sua tv ler essas mensagens, e se a tv pifa tu tem que comprar uma igualzinha. O negócio é fazer um programa de PC que mostre essas mensagens e conectá-lo na TV.

Comment: tem sim, posso ligar a tv do jeito que ficar mais fácil para trabalhar com o sistema

Comment: Por que você não mostra isso no próprio sistema e deixa a TV conectada a um PC?

Comment: Já havia respondido sua dúvida no ActiveDelphi há quase 3 meses atrás: http://www.activedelphi.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?t=89520

Comment: @LuizCarlos Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

O seu problema não é exatamente de programação, mas de entendimento de como o mecanismo funciona em si.

Não digo que é impossível você se comunicar com a TV, dadas as tecnologias atuais, mas dá trabalho e não vai trazer nada útil.

Este problema é resolvido da forma mais trivial possível. Você faz um programa para funcionar em um computador normal e usa a TV como monitor. Se este computador está em rede ou não não fará diferença. Claro que provavelmente estará para receber informações de outros computadores indicando que a fila tem que andar, mas aí o problema já é outro.

Não vou entrar em detalhes porque não é o foco da pergunta, mas o mais provável é que os outros computadores vão se comunicar com este computador que controlará a aplicação de controle de fila através do banco de dados que escolheu usar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Pascal/Conceptual.md).

Comment: entendi o que vc falou. mas neste caso, como faço para que quando o sistema está sendo em outro pc (ou seja o que não tem a tv como monitor) entenda que a mensagem deve ser enviada para o que tem a tv como monitor?

Comment: Você liga um cabo HDMI entre o computador e a sua televisão. Você quer mandar a mensagem para uma ou mais tvs?

Comment: não,, quero que vários pcs ligados na rede enviem mensagem para a tv

Comment: É o que eu falei, o mais fácil são estes computadores, que vão informar que a fila andou para o central ligado na TV, gravarem a informação no banco de dados. Tem várias formas de fazer a comunicação mas acho que para você que está crú é a mais simples. E nem é tão simples assim. Mas já é outra pergunta. Aí você precisa começar fazer algo e ver se tem dúvidas específicas.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica... vou tentar assim...

Comment: Utilize os componentes INDY. Crie um TCPServer no computador onde a TV ficará ligada, e nas máquinas clientes um TCPClient. Então o TCPServer ficará "escutando" uma determinada porta, e basta fazer os clientes enviarem uma informação para o servidor...